# Mysql WHERE Query

Tags: mysql

little help with the query

I have this query

```
SELECT
  link_usluge, id_usluge, naslov_usluge, mesto,
  deo_grada, adresa, telefon, opis,
  naslov_kategorije, kompletno
FROM
  usluge LEFT JOIN kategorija ON koja_kategorija=id_kategorija 
WHERE
  naslov_kategorije LIKE '%auto mehaničar%'
  AND mesto LIKE '%Novi Sad%'
  AND deo_grada LIKE '%Detelinara%'
  AND markevozila LIKE '%SKODA%'
ORDER BY
   id_usluge DESC
```

I need a query to add this, to always in this query have `markevozila='SVE MARKE'`,  means that in mentioned query i have to add all rows that have SVE MARKE in row, and to add rows that have `LIKE markevozila '%SKODA%'` how to query that, any idea?

Txanks a lot

EXAMPLE

> Simple, i want have all results markevozila='SVE MARKE' and to that
>   query i want to add markevozila LIKE '%SKODA%'. In Serbian SVE MARKE
>   means ALLCARS, and markevozila means TYPEOFCARS, that way when some
>   enters AUDI i will query all results for AUDI, but i want to add to
>   that result and all other results that have TYPEOFCARS='ALLCARS

Comment: can you explain your question better? maybe you could prodive some sample data

Comment: Here what i need i have table and inside a row is called markevozila, when some search in that row i use LIKE markevozila '%SKODA%', but i need to add in LIKE SVE MARKE, how to do that?

Comment: in which table do you have markevozila column? in usluge or kategorija ?

Comment: is is ```"SVE MARKE"``` really a value of the column ```markevozila``` in your database, or do you mean it as a placeholder? please paste your ```create tables``` into a sqlfiddle and include data. This seems to be more a language problem than a technical one

Comment: Yes value of the colum, but in that colum i have something like this SKODA,AUDI,BMW,ZASTAVA,SVE MARKE

Comment: then my second guess is close to what you want

Comment: a bit frustrating ... i must admit

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I really understand the question, but I think you just need to change

```
AND markevozila LIKE '%SKODA%'
```

into

```
AND (markevozila LIKE '%SKODA%' OR markevozila LIKE 'SVE MARKE')
```

***EDIT 2:***

it seems the OP wants maybe this?

```
AND (markevozila LIKE '%SKODA%SVE MARKE%' OR markevozila LIKE '%SVE MARKE%SKODA%')
```

Comment: Close, but i dont want to use OR i want to include all two :) Something like AND AND inside row markevozila

Comment: To always have results with SVE MARKE, and different where someone enters, like in this example SKODA

Comment: for that to answer you must provide your schema. please set up a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with your schema and some test data

Comment: I added another possible solution. It is more like guessing what you mean, because you are very vague.

Comment: Simple, i want have all results markevozila='SVE MARKE' and to that query i want to add markevozila LIKE '%SKODA%'. In Serbian SVE MARKE means ALLCARS, and markevozila means TYPEOFCARS, that way when some enters AUDI i will query all results for AUDI, but i want to add to that result and all other results that have TYPEOFCARS='ALLCARS'

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by changing `markevozila  LIKE '%SKODA%'` to `(markevozila = 'SVE MARKE' OR markevozila LIKE '%SKODA%')`:

```
SELECT
  link_usluge, id_usluge, naslov_usluge, mesto,
  deo_grada, adresa, telefon, opis,
  naslov_kategorije, kompletno
FROM
  usluge LEFT JOIN kategorija ON koja_kategorija=id_kategorija 
WHERE
  naslov_kategorije LIKE '%auto mehanicar%'
  AND mesto LIKE '%Novi Sad%'
  AND deo_grada LIKE '%Detelinara%'
  AND (markevozila = 'SVE MARKE' OR markevozila LIKE '%SKODA%')
ORDER BY
   id_usluge DESC
```

It's important to put the parentheses around the `OR` like I've done above - if you don't the expression won't work properly. Let me know if you'd like me to explain the parentheses some more - it's a long explanation but if you need it I'd be happy to write it up.

Comment: Close, but i dont want to use OR i want to include all two :) Something like AND AND inside row markevozila –

Comment: Did you try the query? If I understand your question, it will include both.

Comment: I have tried the query, no luck it has to include both, it it does not :(

Comment: Could you give an example of a couple of rows? Or better yet, could you do a SQL Fiddle like @luksch asked?